# Filling a non empty div with SVG child

Tags: html, css, web, svg

I am trying to place SVG element inside a div with existing content. The SVG should occupy the entire div. Here's some code:

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 50px;">Button
    <svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <rect cx="0" cy="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#00ff00"></rect>
    </svg>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9aw37upL/)

As you can see the svg (in green) is placed below the button label. I would like it to stretch to fill the entire parent div.

My first idea was to use absolute positioning for the SVG and stretch it inside the parent using top, left, right, bottom. The problem is that I can't set parent div position to relative or absolute per my requirements. I also don't control the children of the div, they can be anything.

To give you some context: I'm trying to create a library which plays an animation inside the button when the user clicks it. So the SVG element is attached dynamically to the target elements and I can't make any assumptions on how those elements are positioned and whether they have children or not.

Comment: What kind of animations? Are you doing more than say, rotating a shape?

Comment: If you don't control the layout of the div or the positioning I'm afraid you're probably out of luck other than background images and i'm doubtfull any animation would work there. i really don't understand the contraints your putting on this.

Comment: [Here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/armenbadalyan/ripplejs/master/examples/index.html)'s how the library works. The idea is that users can apply the ripple effect to arbitrary HTML elements without making changes to existing styles.